# Set a variable to a value to be used in latex code?

Tags: graphics, variable

I have a set of sections which contain a few plots. I've given an example below. In my example, each section has one plot, but in reality each section has multiple plots. The code is a copy-paste exercise where I just replace the section name and the folder where the graphs are in each plot. Is there a way to define some sort of a for loop or at least a variable so that when I copy-paste, I don't have to do a find-replace after? I guess I could use an m4 preprocessor but just wondering if latex has something built-in.

```
\section*{foo}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{foo/mean_5min.pdf}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\section*{bar}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{bar/mean_5min.pdf}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Since there is no `\caption` command, I assume you don't want to add a caption nor a label in order to be able to reference the image later on. Since you also use `[H]` I assume you don't want the images to float. Therefore, there is literally no need for the `figure` environment. Since the images are as wide as the textwidth, `\centering` is redundant as well. Since there is only one image per `figure`, I don't understand the use of `subfigure` here. You could get rid of it as well.

Comment: A simple `\section*{foo}

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{foo/mean_5min.pdf}


\section*{bar}

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{bar/mean_5min.pdf}` should give you the exact same output. For even more automatization, you could use `\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}` and get rid of the  repeated `[width=\linewidth]` options.

Comment: You could also use something like `\newcommand{\imagesection}[1]{\section*{#1}\includegraphics{#1/mean_5min.pdf}}` in your preamble and `\imagesection{...}` provided your section name and your directroy name always match. (Be careful though with spaces in directory/file names).

Comment: @leandriis the last comment worked. If you add it as a comment I'll thumbs it up and select it.